# Need help for Unexpected character error with react-redux f7 v3 template

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux

I am not sure if anybody tried redux with framework 7 react template before but I think this is a more general error. I successfully install and run framework 7 react template, then I wanted to try redux. I installed redux, react-redux and tried to integrate todoList example in redux website into same template. I get unexpected character error for some files and I do not know why this happens.

I tried to remove brackets when importing, or added ; end of import lines but didnt change anything.
I copy and paste code directly from redux website, maybe some hidden character problem, how can I test and get rid of that ?

./src/components/Footer.js
Syntax error: D:\client\src\components\Footer.js: Unexpected character ‘​’ (4:0)

```
import React from 'react'
import FilterLink from '../containers/FilterLink'
import { VisibilityFilters } from '../actions'
​
const Footer = () => (
```

./src/reducers/index.js
Syntax error: D:\client\src\reducers\index.js: Unexpected character ‘​’ (5:0)

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import todos from './todos'
import visibilityFilter from './visibilityFilter'

​export default combineReducers({
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you copy/paste directly from the redux examples it looks like there is a zero width space on the blank lines.  In the top right hand corner of the examples there is a copy icon which will copy the actual source code, try that.